# python iterate through subclasses that contain another class

Tags: python

How do I create a loop to iterate through all sub classes that extend another class? For example this `root_node` references `node_2` class that references `node_3` which references `node_4` and so on...In the `linked_list_search` function I am trying to figure out how to append each node `value` to `values_found` but I cant figure out how to loop through a class that extends another class, any tips greatly appreciated.

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node
        
# function to loop through extended classes
def linked_list_search(node,search_term):
    
    #print(node.next_node.__dict__)

    values_found = []
    for next_n in node.next_node.__dict__.values():
        if isinstance(next_n,int):
            values_found.append(next_n)
            
    print(values_found)
    
    
node_7 = LinkedListNode(5)
node_6 = LinkedListNode(2, node_7)
node_5 = LinkedListNode(9, node_6)
node_4 = LinkedListNode(1, node_5)
node_3 = LinkedListNode(4, node_4)
node_2 = LinkedListNode(6, node_3)
root_node = LinkedListNode(7, node_2)
```

Comment: There are no subclasses here, only references to objects of type `LinkedListNode`. The fact that no node knows anything else except the single node *it* points to is what makes this a linked list.

Comment: You probably want `if node.value == search_term: values_fond.append(...)`. (Not sure if you want the node itself or the value in the list.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to write current visiting node into some variable:

```
def linked_list_search(node,search_term):
    
    values_found = []
    while node:
        if isinstance(node.value,int):
            values_found.append(node.value)
        node = node.next_node
            
    print(values_found)
```

Comment: Nice thank you ill hit the green check when I can. How does the while loop work? `while node`...still trying to soak that in

Comment: `node`, like anything else, has a "truthiness" value. Unless you define it other wise, an object is simply true. `None`, on the other hand, is false. `while node is not None:` would probably be clearer.